# ERROR: Failed building wheel for cytoolz when installing web3.py on macOS

Tags: python, python-wheel, web3py

while trying to do

```
pip install web3
```

I am always getting the following error

> Building wheel for cytoolz (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Command
> errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 -u -c
> 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/private/var/folders/gb/5fvn1z1s689bzt7vbll5845c0000gn/T/pip-install-cxwpjegv/cytoolz_88244d2146254468892c582d0b9e33fa/setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'/private/var/folders/gb/5fvn1z1s689bzt7vbll5845c0000gn/T/pip-install-cxwpjegv/cytoolz_88244d2146254468892c582d0b9e33fa/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d
> /private/var/folders/gb/5fvn1z1s689bzt7vbll5845c0000gn/T/pip-wheel-ljv1jb3k
> cwd: /private/var/folders/gb/5fvn1z1s689bzt7vbll5845c0000gn/T/pip-install-cxwpjegv/cytoolz_88244d2146254468892c582d0b9e33fa/
> Complete output (56 lines):   [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/utils.pyx
> [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx   [3/5] Cythonizing
> cytoolz/functoolz.pyx   [4/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx
> [5/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/recipes.pyx   running bdist_wheel   running
> build   running build_py   creating build   creating
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10   creating
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/compatibility.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
> copying cytoolz/**init**.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/_signatures.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   creating
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried   copying
> cytoolz/curried/operator.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried   copying
> cytoolz/curried/**init**.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried   copying
> cytoolz/curried/exceptions.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/curried   copying
> cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
> copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/functoolz.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
> copying cytoolz/recipes.pyx ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/utils.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
> copying cytoolz/utils.pxd ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/**init**.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
> copying cytoolz/recipes.pxd ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/functoolz.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
> copying cytoolz/dicttoolz.pxd ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   copying
> cytoolz/cpython.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz
> copying cytoolz/itertoolz.pxd ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   creating
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_none_safe.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_utils.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_curried.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_compatibility.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_embedded_sigs.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_functoolz.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_inspect_args.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_doctests.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_tlz.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_signatures.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/dev_skip_test.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_recipes.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_docstrings.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_dev_skip_test.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_dicttoolz.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_serialization.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_curried_toolzlike.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   copying
> cytoolz/tests/test_itertoolz.py ->
> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/tests   running
> build_ext   creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10   creating
> build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz   clang
> -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10
> -c cytoolz/dicttoolz.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/cytoolz/dicttoolz.o   xcrun:
> error: invalid active developer path
> (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun   error: command
> '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for cytoolz

I have tried to update wheel, installing with sudo, and nothing worked so far,
would love for some help,
thanks

Comment: I can't find how to edit but I am using a Mac

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun+

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to install xcode tools using

```
xcode-select --install
```